# Chrome opens one window after another. And another. And another

Tags: google-chrome

Every time I use Chrome (49.0.2623.112 for Mac, OS 10.6.8) ... EVERY TIME ... when I try to scroll to read an article, a new window opens. I go back to the window I was reading, read a little more, a new window opens. Over and over. New windows. About viruses. About Flash. About everything you can imagine except the article I'm trying to read. I don't have any extensions. I hate Chrome. If there's no way to stop this, I'll stop using it and go back to Firefox (which I'm using to write this message). Does anyone know anything useful about this?

Comment: At least run Malwarebytes over your machine; if you can find one that will still run on 10.6.8. Best I could find was for 10.7 - https://support.malwarebytes.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2168368-what-operating-system-is-required-for-anti-malware-for-mac-?b_id=6400

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Answer (score 0):

> **Reset Chrome settings to default**
>
> You can restore your browser settings in Chrome at any time. You might
>   need to do this if apps or extensions you installed changed your
>   settings without your knowledge. Your saved bookmarks and passwords
>   won't be cleared or changed.
>
> 1. On your computer, open Chrome.
> 2. At the top right, click More [image] and then **Settings**.
> 3. At the bottom, click **Show advanced settings**.
> 4. Under the section "Reset settings,” click **Reset settings**.
> 5. In the box that appears, click **Reset**. ​
>
> These steps won't provide a full reset. For example, some settings
>   like fonts or accessibility won't be deleted. To create a new user
>   profile, [add a new user in Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824).
>
> **What changes when you restore your settings**
>
> The following settings will change back to the default:
>
> - **Default search engine**, which is changed back to Google.
> - **Homepage and tabs**.
> - **The new tab page**.
> - **Content settings**, like letting a site show you pop-ups or use your    microphone.
> - **Cookies and site data**, like items in an online shopping cart.
> - **Extensions and themes**.
>
> Only the settings for the Chrome profile you're signed in to will be
>   reset. Your new settings will apply across all computers or devices
>   where you’re signed in to your active profile. [Source](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3296214?hl=en).

Or if else fails, reinstalling Chrome would be the better bet.

Comment: Hi, it appears that you copied this answer from https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3296214?hl=en. You're using someone's work without giving the author credit. This amounts to plagiarism, and is not welcome on [SU]. Remember to always add prominent attribution and appropriate block quoting when using other sources. Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing).

Comment: I've fixed it for you this time. Please take care in future to correctly quote.